# Django QuerySet .count() is 0 and .exists() is false, even though there's an object in the QuerySet (Django Rest Framework)

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, django-rest-framework, amazon-rds

I've had an intermittent bug for months and I am stuck! Help is appreciated.

```
class ContentFile(models.Model):
    """
    Represents the metadata for a single document.
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    set = models.ForeignKey(Set, related_name='contentfile_set', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = models.FileField(upload_to=get_content_file_upload_path)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'ProtocolManager'
        unique_together = ('set', 'location')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"File {self.name} at location {str(self.location)} attached to {self.set}"


@receiver(models.signals.post_delete, sender=ContentFile)
def delete_file(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Delete orphaned file once last ContentFile is removed.
    """
    log.info(f"Checking {instance.location} for existing ContentFile")
    if instance.location:
        from django.db import connection
        from django.db import reset_queries
        reset_queries()
        files_queryset = ContentFile.objects.filter(location=instance.location)
        if not files_queryset.exists():
            log.info(f"ContentFile does not exist for {instance.location}, deleting...")
            log.info(f"SQL: {connection.queries}")
            log.info(f"files_queryset: {list(files_queryset.all())}")
            log.info(f"count: {files_queryset.count()}")
            log.info(f"exists: {files_queryset.exists()}")
            instance.location.delete(save=False)
```

The logic is pretty simple. When a ContentFile row is deleted, if it was the last one referring to an actual file location, we delete the file itself (on AWS S3, if it matters). 99% of the time this works as expected, but sometimes it will fail, and when it fails, it seems to fail for all of the ContentFiles associated with a given Set. I added the verbose logging to try to get more clues, but today it finally reproduced for the first time in months and the logging is just frustrating:

```
...
2021-06-08 20:30:05,329 [INFO] ProtocolManager.models: Checking 1129/314.pdf for existing ContentFile
2021-06-08 20:30:05,335 [INFO] ProtocolManager.models: ContentFile does not exist for 1129/314.pdf, deleting...
2021-06-08 20:30:05,335 [INFO] ProtocolManager.models: SQL: [{'sql': "SELECT (1) AS `a` FROM `ProtocolManager_contentfile` WHERE `ProtocolManager_contentfile`.`location` = '1129/314.pdf' LIMIT 1", 'time': '0.005'}]
2021-06-08 20:30:05,604 [INFO] ProtocolManager.models: files_queryset: [<ContentFile: File hypovolemic-traumatic-shockpdf.pdf at location 1129/314.pdf attached to Set v2021.6.8 '586-Joachim-Plattin Ambulance PCG' (1130-EDIT)>]
2021-06-08 20:30:05,610 [INFO] ProtocolManager.models: count: 0
2021-06-08 20:30:05,618 [INFO] ProtocolManager.models: exists: False
2021-06-08 20:30:05,685 [INFO] ProtocolManager.models: Checking 1116/312.pdf for existing ContentFile
2021-06-08 20:30:05,690 [INFO] ProtocolManager.models: Checking 1109/310.pdf for existing ContentFile
2021-06-08 20:30:05,700 [INFO] ProtocolManager.models: Checking 1101/306.pdf for existing ContentFile
2021-06-08 20:30:05,705 [INFO] ProtocolManager.models: Checking 1095/304.pdf for existing ContentFile
2021-06-08 20:30:05,711 [INFO] ProtocolManager.models: Checking 1089/301.pdf for existing ContentFile
2021-06-08 20:30:05,721 [INFO] ProtocolManager.models: Checking 1083/296.pdf for existing ContentFile
2021-06-08 20:30:05,726 [INFO] ProtocolManager.models: Checking 1080/292.pdf for existing ContentFile
2021-06-08 20:30:05,734 [INFO] ProtocolManager.models: Checking 1077/290.pdf for existing ContentFile
2021-06-08 20:30:05,739 [INFO] ProtocolManager.models: Checking 1075/289.pdf for existing ContentFile
2021-06-08 20:30:05,747 [INFO] ProtocolManager.models: Checking 1072/287.pdf for existing ContentFile
2021-06-08 20:30:05,754 [INFO] ProtocolManager.models: Checking 1066/285.pdf for existing ContentFile
2021-06-08 20:30:05,763 [INFO] ProtocolManager.models: Checking 1129/307.pdf for existing ContentFile
2021-06-08 20:30:05,768 [INFO] ProtocolManager.models: ContentFile does not exist for 1129/307.pdf, deleting...
2021-06-08 20:30:05,768 [INFO] ProtocolManager.models: SQL: [{'sql': "SELECT (1) AS `a` FROM `ProtocolManager_contentfile` WHERE `ProtocolManager_contentfile`.`location` = '1129/307.pdf' LIMIT 1", 'time': '0.004'}]
2021-06-08 20:30:05,943 [INFO] ProtocolManager.models: files_queryset: [<ContentFile: File 0004-ift-medications.pdf at location 1129/307.pdf attached to Set v2021.6.8 '586-Joachim-Plattin Ambulance PCG' (1130-EDIT)>]
2021-06-08 20:30:05,947 [INFO] ProtocolManager.models: count: 0
2021-06-08 20:30:05,952 [INFO] ProtocolManager.models: exists: False
2021-06-08 20:30:05,982 [INFO] ProtocolManager.models: Checking 855/123.pdf for existing ContentFile
2021-06-08 20:30:05,987 [INFO] ProtocolManager.models: Checking 1096/122.pdf for existing ContentFile
2021-06-08 20:30:05,992 [INFO] ProtocolManager.models: Checking 855/121.pdf for existing ContentFile
2021-06-08 20:30:05,997 [INFO] ProtocolManager.models: Checking 1116/295.pdf for existing ContentFile
...
```

In the log it shows that there is in fact the expected ContentFile row at the location in question (the output from `list(files_queryset.all())`) but both count() is 0 and exists() is false.

Does anyone have any ideas why this might be happening? Intermittent database issues to AWS RDS, perhaps?

The database log in the same period (note I removed some extraneous fields from the Model above for clarity, you still see them in the DB queries themselves):

```
2021-06-08 20:30:05,335 [DEBUG] django.db.backends: (0.005) SELECT (1) AS `a` FROM `ProtocolManager_contentfile` WHERE `ProtocolManager_contentfile`.`location` = '1129/314.pdf' LIMIT 1; args=('1129/314.pdf',)
2021-06-08 20:30:05,593 [DEBUG] django.db.backends: (0.257) SELECT `ProtocolManager_contentfile`.`id`, `ProtocolManager_contentfile`.`name`, `ProtocolManager_contentfile`.`set_id`, `ProtocolManager_contentfile`.`location`, `ProtocolManager_contentfile`.`extractedText`, `ProtocolManager_contentfile`.`pages`, `ProtocolManager_contentfile`.`md5`, `ProtocolManager_contentfile`.`fileSize`, `ProtocolManager_contentfile`.`createdOn`, `ProtocolManager_contentfile`.`createdBy_id`, `ProtocolManager_contentfile`.`lastUpdated`, `ProtocolManager_contentfile`.`updatedBy_id` FROM `ProtocolManager_contentfile` WHERE `ProtocolManager_contentfile`.`location` = '1129/314.pdf'; args=('1129/314.pdf',)
2021-06-08 20:30:05,602 [DEBUG] django.db.backends: (0.007) SELECT `ProtocolManager_set`.`id`, `ProtocolManager_set`.`setMeta_id`, `ProtocolManager_set`.`originSet_id`, `ProtocolManager_set`.`majorVersion`, `ProtocolManager_set`.`minorVersion`, `ProtocolManager_set`.`revisionVersion`, `ProtocolManager_set`.`acknowledgmentSetID`, `ProtocolManager_set`.`receiptAckText`, `ProtocolManager_set`.`pubLevel`, `ProtocolManager_set`.`minOSiOS`, `ProtocolManager_set`.`minOSAndroid`, `ProtocolManager_set`.`minVersioniOS`, `ProtocolManager_set`.`minVersionAndroid`, `ProtocolManager_set`.`createdOn`, `ProtocolManager_set`.`createdBy_id`, `ProtocolManager_set`.`lastUpdated`, `ProtocolManager_set`.`updatedBy_id` FROM `ProtocolManager_set` WHERE `ProtocolManager_set`.`id` = 1130 LIMIT 21; args=(1130,)
2021-06-08 20:30:05,604 [DEBUG] django.db.backends: (0.001) SELECT `ProtocolManager_setmeta`.`id`, `ProtocolManager_setmeta`.`region_id`, `ProtocolManager_setmeta`.`setName`, `ProtocolManager_setmeta`.`displayName`, `ProtocolManager_setmeta`.`isOffline`, `ProtocolManager_setmeta`.`offlineReason`, `ProtocolManager_setmeta`.`discontinued`, `ProtocolManager_setmeta`.`invisible`, `ProtocolManager_setmeta`.`isSponsored`, `ProtocolManager_setmeta`.`isOutdated`, `ProtocolManager_setmeta`.`lastUID`, `ProtocolManager_setmeta`.`companyNumberLabel`, `ProtocolManager_setmeta`.`companyNumberRegex`, `ProtocolManager_setmeta`.`customBundleId`, `ProtocolManager_setmeta`.`betaEnabled`, `ProtocolManager_setmeta`.`restrictedMD5`, `ProtocolManager_setmeta`.`createdOn`, `ProtocolManager_setmeta`.`lastUpdated`, `ProtocolManager_setmeta`.`createdBy_id`, `ProtocolManager_setmeta`.`updatedBy_id` FROM `ProtocolManager_setmeta` WHERE `ProtocolManager_setmeta`.`id` = 586 LIMIT 21; args=(586,)
2021-06-08 20:30:05,610 [DEBUG] django.db.backends: (0.005) SELECT COUNT(*) AS `__count` FROM `ProtocolManager_contentfile` WHERE `ProtocolManager_contentfile`.`location` = '1129/314.pdf'; args=('1129/314.pdf',)
2021-06-08 20:30:05,617 [DEBUG] django.db.backends: (0.007) SELECT (1) AS `a` FROM `ProtocolManager_contentfile` WHERE `ProtocolManager_contentfile`.`location` = '1129/314.pdf' LIMIT 1; args=('1129/314.pdf',)
2021-06-08 20:30:05,690 [DEBUG] django.db.backends: (0.004) SELECT (1) AS `a` FROM `ProtocolManager_contentfile` WHERE `ProtocolManager_contentfile`.`location` = '1116/312.pdf' LIMIT 1; args=('1116/312.pdf',)
2021-06-08 20:30:05,700 [DEBUG] django.db.backends: (0.009) SELECT (1) AS `a` FROM `ProtocolManager_contentfile` WHERE `ProtocolManager_contentfile`.`location` = '1109/310.pdf' LIMIT 1; args=('1109/310.pdf',)
2021-06-08 20:30:05,705 [DEBUG] django.db.backends: (0.004) SELECT (1) AS `a` FROM `ProtocolManager_contentfile` WHERE `ProtocolManager_contentfile`.`location` = '1101/306.pdf' LIMIT 1; args=('1101/306.pdf',)
2021-06-08 20:30:05,711 [DEBUG] django.db.backends: (0.006) SELECT (1) AS `a` FROM `ProtocolManager_contentfile` WHERE `ProtocolManager_contentfile`.`location` = '1095/304.pdf' LIMIT 1; args=('1095/304.pdf',)
2021-06-08 20:30:05,721 [DEBUG] django.db.backends: (0.009) SELECT (1) AS `a` FROM `ProtocolManager_contentfile` WHERE `ProtocolManager_contentfile`.`location` = '1089/301.pdf' LIMIT 1; args=('1089/301.pdf',)
2021-06-08 20:30:05,725 [DEBUG] django.db.backends: (0.004) SELECT (1) AS `a` FROM `ProtocolManager_contentfile` WHERE `ProtocolManager_contentfile`.`location` = '1083/296.pdf' LIMIT 1; args=('1083/296.pdf',)
2021-06-08 20:30:05,734 [DEBUG] django.db.backends: (0.008) SELECT (1) AS `a` FROM `ProtocolManager_contentfile` WHERE `ProtocolManager_contentfile`.`location` = '1080/292.pdf' LIMIT 1; args=('1080/292.pdf',)
2021-06-08 20:30:05,739 [DEBUG] django.db.backends: (0.004) SELECT (1) AS `a` FROM `ProtocolManager_contentfile` WHERE `ProtocolManager_contentfile`.`location` = '1077/290.pdf' LIMIT 1; args=('1077/290.pdf',)
2021-06-08 20:30:05,746 [DEBUG] django.db.backends: (0.007) SELECT (1) AS `a` FROM `ProtocolManager_contentfile` WHERE `ProtocolManager_contentfile`.`location` = '1075/289.pdf' LIMIT 1; args=('1075/289.pdf',)
2021-06-08 20:30:05,754 [DEBUG] django.db.backends: (0.007) SELECT (1) AS `a` FROM `ProtocolManager_contentfile` WHERE `ProtocolManager_contentfile`.`location` = '1072/287.pdf' LIMIT 1; args=('1072/287.pdf',)
2021-06-08 20:30:05,762 [DEBUG] django.db.backends: (0.007) SELECT (1) AS `a` FROM `ProtocolManager_contentfile` WHERE `ProtocolManager_contentfile`.`location` = '1066/285.pdf' LIMIT 1; args=('1066/285.pdf',)
2021-06-08 20:30:05,767 [DEBUG] django.db.backends: (0.004) SELECT (1) AS `a` FROM `ProtocolManager_contentfile` WHERE `ProtocolManager_contentfile`.`location` = '1129/307.pdf' LIMIT 1; args=('1129/307.pdf',)
2021-06-08 20:30:05,937 [DEBUG] django.db.backends: (0.169) SELECT `ProtocolManager_contentfile`.`id`, `ProtocolManager_contentfile`.`name`, `ProtocolManager_contentfile`.`set_id`, `ProtocolManager_contentfile`.`location`, `ProtocolManager_contentfile`.`extractedText`, `ProtocolManager_contentfile`.`pages`, `ProtocolManager_contentfile`.`md5`, `ProtocolManager_contentfile`.`fileSize`, `ProtocolManager_contentfile`.`createdOn`, `ProtocolManager_contentfile`.`createdBy_id`, `ProtocolManager_contentfile`.`lastUpdated`, `ProtocolManager_contentfile`.`updatedBy_id` FROM `ProtocolManager_contentfile` WHERE `ProtocolManager_contentfile`.`location` = '1129/307.pdf'; args=('1129/307.pdf',)
2021-06-08 20:30:05,940 [DEBUG] django.db.backends: (0.001) SELECT `ProtocolManager_set`.`id`, `ProtocolManager_set`.`setMeta_id`, `ProtocolManager_set`.`originSet_id`, `ProtocolManager_set`.`majorVersion`, `ProtocolManager_set`.`minorVersion`, `ProtocolManager_set`.`revisionVersion`, `ProtocolManager_set`.`acknowledgmentSetID`, `ProtocolManager_set`.`receiptAckText`, `ProtocolManager_set`.`pubLevel`, `ProtocolManager_set`.`minOSiOS`, `ProtocolManager_set`.`minOSAndroid`, `ProtocolManager_set`.`minVersioniOS`, `ProtocolManager_set`.`minVersionAndroid`, `ProtocolManager_set`.`createdOn`, `ProtocolManager_set`.`createdBy_id`, `ProtocolManager_set`.`lastUpdated`, `ProtocolManager_set`.`updatedBy_id` FROM `ProtocolManager_set` WHERE `ProtocolManager_set`.`id` = 1130 LIMIT 21; args=(1130,)
2021-06-08 20:30:05,942 [DEBUG] django.db.backends: (0.001) SELECT `ProtocolManager_setmeta`.`id`, `ProtocolManager_setmeta`.`region_id`, `ProtocolManager_setmeta`.`setName`, `ProtocolManager_setmeta`.`displayName`, `ProtocolManager_setmeta`.`isOffline`, `ProtocolManager_setmeta`.`offlineReason`, `ProtocolManager_setmeta`.`discontinued`, `ProtocolManager_setmeta`.`invisible`, `ProtocolManager_setmeta`.`isSponsored`, `ProtocolManager_setmeta`.`isOutdated`, `ProtocolManager_setmeta`.`lastUID`, `ProtocolManager_setmeta`.`companyNumberLabel`, `ProtocolManager_setmeta`.`companyNumberRegex`, `ProtocolManager_setmeta`.`customBundleId`, `ProtocolManager_setmeta`.`betaEnabled`, `ProtocolManager_setmeta`.`restrictedMD5`, `ProtocolManager_setmeta`.`createdOn`, `ProtocolManager_setmeta`.`lastUpdated`, `ProtocolManager_setmeta`.`createdBy_id`, `ProtocolManager_setmeta`.`updatedBy_id` FROM `ProtocolManager_setmeta` WHERE `ProtocolManager_setmeta`.`id` = 586 LIMIT 21; args=(586,)
2021-06-08 20:30:05,947 [DEBUG] django.db.backends: (0.004) SELECT COUNT(*) AS `__count` FROM `ProtocolManager_contentfile` WHERE `ProtocolManager_contentfile`.`location` = '1129/307.pdf'; args=('1129/307.pdf',)
2021-06-08 20:30:05,952 [DEBUG] django.db.backends: (0.004) SELECT (1) AS `a` FROM `ProtocolManager_contentfile` WHERE `ProtocolManager_contentfile`.`location` = '1129/307.pdf' LIMIT 1; args=('1129/307.pdf',)
```

Comment: Are `ContentFiles` deleted through a `Set`? If yes, it could be possible to move this operation to the `Set` and batch them. The issue could stem from the interpreter  invoking the signal handler many times in the same request lifecycle. Also there is also the chance that this is a weak signal and it's being garbage collected before end of the request.

Comment: It's not a cascade delete, but when a Set changes state in a particular way, yes, the associated ContentFiles get deleted. How do you think the signal handler invocation may be the culprit? Does that make sense given the behavior (that there is something in the QuerySet, but the COUNT is 0?)

Answer (score 1):

You might have a corrupted index on the `ProtocolManager_contentfile` table.

[This question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/202044/select-count-returning-incorrect-results) seems to have been dealing with a similar phenomenon. If this is the cause of your problem, you would probably need to `REINDEX` your database.

Comment: Is there a better way to test this possibility than going for a REINDEX? It was also happening in multiple databases (at random, in dev and production, which were divergent since this error always occurs when workon on new Sets/ContentFiles)

Comment: @Oded You could try those queries (`exist`, `count`, `all`) using a problematic filename outside of the `post_delete` receiver. If it is still returning inconsistent results, connect to the db with a client like pgAdmin and manually run the select queries in your database log. If still inconsistent, you can discount Django as the culprit.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that it's not reproducible. Even when I catch it and restore to point-in-time, the subsequent execution of the code behaves correctly.

Comment: Well, this didn't end up solving it, but the bounty is up and you tried the hardest, so awarding to you.

Comment: @Oded Thanks. Wish I could offer a better solution, but it has me stumped too.